# Connection issues using pandas.Dataframe.to_sql and sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to insert a Pandas dataframe into an SQL Server I have running on Docker. I'm using python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
# import the module
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

# create sqlalchemy engine
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pw}@{sv}:1433/{db}"
                       .format(user="sa",
                               pw="sa",
                               db="fuel_check_hist",
                               sv='192.168.86.39'))

# Insert whole DataFrame into MySQL
df.to_sql('prices', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000, index = False)
```

gives me the following error

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Note the following code does work so I do know that my instance of SQL Server is available and pyodbc can connect to it.

```
import pyodbc 
server = '192.168.86.39' 
database = 'fuel_check_hist' 
username = 'sa' 
password = 'sa' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#Sample select query
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
>       Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
>       Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
>       Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) **

Comment: off topic , but you should NOT be using the 'sa' user to connect to your database. Any DBA that knows their stuff will have disabled the 'sa' user....

Comment: I'm just learning about connecting Python to MSSQL in my sandbox. Nothing here is connected to the internet and I'm definitely not using any of this environment for production.

Answer (score 2):

Ok figured it out, I needed to add a string to specify the driver in the connection parameters.
'?driver=ODBC+DRIVER+17+for+SQL+Server'

```py
# create sqlalchemy engine
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pw}@{sv}:1433/{db}?driver=ODBC+DRIVER+17+for+SQL+Server"
                       .format(user="sa",
                               pw="sa",
                               db="fuel_check_hist",
                               sv='192.168.86.39'))
```

Helpful links

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections
- https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/